# Create-React-App build folder missing files

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have run create-react-app and started development on my app. `yarn start` works perfectly and the app runs in browser with several components and imported images. However, when I run `yarn build` not all of the images are moved to build/static/media (please see image below).

[Folder structure and terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqvK0.png)

There are no errors in the terminal output other than a warning about an arrow function which I have since removed with no success.

Is it still building an old version from when I only had panorama.jpg? Please advise.

Comment: I believe all the files from the `public` folder are only copied directly to the build folder. Is there any manual task that you are running to copy `src/img` folder?

Comment: No, I've deleted the build folder several times and simply run ```yarn build``` as specified in the readme. That results in what you see in the image. panorama.jpg ends up in the build folder but none of the other images.

Comment: Try putting all the images once in `public` folder. Check if that is working?

Comment: That results in the following error ```Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../../public/img/panorama.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.```

Comment: Import using `/img/panorama.jpg` instead of a relative path. Whatever is in public folder, you should import starting with `/` and then the public relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your images to /public folder.